# OrchardCMS Infoset and partrecord getting out of sync

Tags: orchardcms

I'm finding that my partrecord (backing record) and infoset record are getting out sync, when using ContentItemVersionRecord.

The site has been developed using dynamic forms, and custom part records, such as...

```
public class ParticipantPartRecord : ContentPartVersionRecord
{
    public virtual string ParticipantId { get; set; }
}

public class ParticipantPart : ContentPart<ParticipantPartRecord>, ITitleAspect
{
   public string ParticipantId {
       get { return Retrieve(r => r.ParticipantId); } 
       set { Store(s => s.ParticipantId, value); } }
}
```

When updating (I'm using a fork of the dynamic forms module which allows edits - see issue 6163) a record through a DynamicForm the FormController creates a draft of the ContentItem, updates the bindings, and publishes the ContentItem, which updates the infoset record in ContentItemVersionRecord and (I assume) triggers an update of the backing record.

There are some fields which I update via workflows (as they are generated programatically, rather than user set on the form). When I update these records (on the previously published draft, so latest version), the infoset updates, however the backing record does not seem to.

As most of the data retrieval is using _contentManager.Get(id) I hadn't noticed the issue, however when using _contentManager.Query.Where() on the programatically updated records, I discovered that the backing record no longer matched the InfoSet record in Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord

When updating the records programatically in the workflows I'm using code like

```
var participant = workflowContext.Content.ContentItem.As<ParticipantPart>();
participant.ParticipantId = GenerateParticipantId();
```

This updates the InfoSet record in ContentItemVersionRecord, but the backing record does not appear to be updating.

I haven't used VersionedRecords before, and I wonder if I need to be creating a draft, and publishing in order to force the backing record to update, or if there is something in the Handler that needs to be set to trigger the update to the backing record.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I have experienced a similar thing and never found a resolution...

Comment: No I haven't. Due to other SQL N+1 issues I had to rearrange the Query arrangement, and during the refactor of this went away from querying the record directly, and stayed with the data coming from the store.